# Can't open tomcat home page on vps

Tags: tomcat

I installed tomcat on my vps (using binary files, not apt-get install). I can start it without problems using bin/startup.sh:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7                                                                                       
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7                                                                                       
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp                                                                                  
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle                                                                               
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar                              
Tomcat started.
```

But when I try to open tomcat homepage it shows an error - can't show the page: http://185.18.54.199:8080/
VPS hosting support tells that the course may be in the lack of heap memory. I have 512 MB. I suppose it is enough for just starting tomcat homepage. 
Can you please tell, why this error can appear?
Thank you

Comment: Have you set environment variables?

Comment: I am new with it - aren't these environment variables? root@kvmnl05-7311:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin# echo $JAVA_HOME                                                                       
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle                                                                                                      
root@kvmnl05-7311:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin# echo $CATALINA_HOME                                                                   
/usr/share/tomcat7

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you problem with Java EE rather then Tomcat.

> The minimum and recommended memory and disk space requirements are as
>   follows:
>
> Minimum memory: 1 GB 
>   Recommended memory: 2 GB for Windows platforms, 
>   1 GB for non-Windows platforms 
>   Minimum disk space: 250 MB 
>   Recommended disk space: 500 MB

Here is the link that specifies aforementioned quote: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/javaee7sdk-readme-1957703.html#System_Requirements

Comment: is anywhere a file with logs, where the memory problem is logged?

Comment: you must check first $TOMCAT_HOME/log/catalina.out that is Tomcat log file

Comment: thank you. I cleared it, afterwards shutdown the tomcat. Looked in catalina.out - there were no errors. Cleared again. Started tomcat. And saw the error in catalina.out - this post is already used:         SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]                                        
java.net.BindException: Адрес уже используется <null>:8080

Comment: I used netstat -tulpn to find out which port uses 8080 port. It is "apache2". tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1278/apache2  .           Please, tell me - should I change tomcat port?

Comment: now it starts after I changed port to 8181 in tomcat configuration file. Thank you everybody for help!

Comment: @AlexeyRumin marking question or vote up helps us to actively help in this community. Please mark answer or vote up

Comment: @Chayel I don't understand, how should I mark the question

Comment: @AlexeyRumin you can accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work